# Meaning of Large Dataset for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, datasets

Some online answers about parameters in machine learning mention that it is dependent on the size of dataset we have (if it is a large dataset or not). Is this size related to the number of samples we have or to the number of features for each sample, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statistical and deep learning models **usually** have parameters size that depends on the number of features of the input data when doing supervised learning. Note that this is a very high-level answer and there might be specific models that have params size depending on the number of data points as well.

Let me give you a basic example to clarify the above:

For a simple multivariate linear regression, we use a linear model denoted as $f(x_i)$ and parametrized by $\theta = (\theta_0, \ldots, \theta_d)$ where $d$ is the number of features of each data points $x_i$. The model is also perturbed by some Gaussian noise $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$, also called error. Overall it is defined as:

\begin{equation}
\hat{y_i} = f(x_i; \theta) + \epsilon_i := \langle \theta,  x_{i} \rangle + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

The objective of the learning phase is now to fit the parameter $\theta$ in order to minimise the discrepancy between the predictions $\hat{y}_i$ and sone ground truth labels. The only parameters you can tune in this model are precisely the entries of the vector $\theta$, which is of size $d$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification!